# Уведомления от приложения, даже когда оно закрыто

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Приветствую. Знаете игру Shadow Fight 2 для смартфонов? Так вот, там, даже если приложение закрыто, оно напоминает уведомлениями о своем существовании.

Даже при закрытом приложении приходят уведомления типа: "Враги заждались тебя!"

Есть код который я нашел, он прекрасно работает, но как сделать так, чтобы приложение само отправляло уведомление допустим 1 раз в день в одно же время?

Код:

```
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;

public void showNotification(View view) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    // до версии Android 8.0 API 26
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            // обязательные настройки
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.amber_game)
            //.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) // Заголовок уведомления
            .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
            //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
            .setContentText("Поиграй в игру!") // Текст уведомления
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true); // автоматически закрыть уведомление после нажатия
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Используй service и broadcast'ы. Там, с помощью  GregorianCalendar, можно брать текущее время и показывать уведомление каждый день в это же время, к примеру.      P.S Пример реализации Gregorian'a: GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int week = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // возвращает день недели
       int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //возвращает часы
       int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //возвращает минуты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, в названном приложении скорее всего используется [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm), а во-вторых, если все же решили обойтись без этого, то используйте [Alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)`ы, что позволит выполнить какое-то действие в заданное время. Пример релизации можете почитать здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/34130/, но учтите, что прошло много времени и требования к реализации могли измениться.

Comment: AlarmManager - то, что мне нужно. Спасибо.